# How to end for loop at a certain index in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, for-loop

I have a table in which I will loop an array to display its contents. I want to limit the number of items that I will display in the table.

```
<tr
  class="table__row"
  v-for="(leaveRequest, index) in leaveRequests.slice(top)"
  :key="index"
>
```

I'm trying to find a way to end this for loop at a certain index, so that I can display only a certain amount of items. The `slice` array method is for me to start at a certain index.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If `top` is where you want to end at, then `.slice(0, top)` should work